# In Confluence Is There A Way to Display the Contents of an Attached File in a CODE BLOCK?

Tags: confluence

I am editing some Confluence pages and I need to display the contents of a SQL file on the page.  I have attached the file and can copy and paste into a Code Block.  But what they want is the attached file to show up displayed on the page.  Is there a way (preferably in a code block so it can be formatted) to display the contents of a text file that is attached to the page actually on the page?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is if there is a macro that would take the attachment and write it to the page for you.  There are a number of macros, but I don't know if one of them does what you are looking for. A quick look through the stock macros doesn't reveal an obvious answer.  You could write your own, however.

Click on + Insert, Other Macros, and select Development, then check out the Cheese demo.

[From the documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf54/confluence-user-s-guide/creating-content/using-the-editor/working-with-macros/cheese-macro):

> To edit an existing macro: Click the macro placeholder and choose Edit. A macro dialog window will open, where you can edit the parameters of the macro.

The Code Block macro does support sql file formatting, but you would have to insert the content of the sql into the document.  You might create a derivative of this macro to accomplish your goal.